# How to trigger CuteUpload's UploadStart event using Jjavascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to trigger a Javascript function after CuteUpload's upload event start, but I don't understand how to call the event.

Any help would be nice.

Here is the [user manual](http://www.cuteupload.com/user_manual.html), with some confusing explanation about Javascript events can be found at bottom of the page.

Comment: This looks like a very outdated ActiveX plugin. Last update in 2007, and only works in IE . If you don't have to use this, I would recommend using the native file upload via HTML forms - see the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this information. Looks like my project uses ajax uploader, not this old one. Your warn was very helpfull